# In my code, how could I make an update so that the trs and the th selected don't get selected if their display is none?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm currently trying to make a filter to my pivot table, but I don't know how I can responsively calculate the sum of each row/column, depending on the one that are displayed or not. If you need any other part of my code, you can ask freely. To hide the employees, I put the display of the trs to none, and to hide the process, I put the display of the tds and th of the column to none.

Here is the code in JS and I'll put a screenshot of the pivot table too :

```js
function countTotal() {
   const tables = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('tbody'));
   tables.forEach(table => {
      const trs = Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName('tr')).slice(1);
      const employees = Array.from(trs.map(tr => tr.childNodes[1].classList[0])).remove('total-col');

      employees.forEach(employee => {
         let colSum = 0;
         const cells = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName(employee)).slice(1, -1);
         cells.forEach(cell => {
            const textContent = parseFloat(cell.innerHTML.trim());
            colSum += !Number.isNaN(textContent) ? textContent : 0;
         });
         let cellToFill = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName(employee)).slice(-1)[0];
         cellToFill.textContent = colSum.round(2);
      });

      const processes = Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('th')).map(th => th.classList[0]).remove(undefined);
      processes.forEach(process => {
         let rowSum = 0;
         const cells = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName(process)).slice(1, -1);
         cells.forEach(cell => {
            const textContent = parseFloat(cell.innerHTML.trim());
            rowSum += !Number.isNaN(textContent) ? textContent : 0;
         });
         let cellToFill = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName(process)).slice(-1)[0];
         cellToFill.textContent = rowSum.round(2);
      });
   });
}
```

[![Screenshot of the pivot table][1]][1]

Edit :

Here is the code where I change my display.

```js
var filters = document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxes'); // 0 => employee ; 1 => process ; 2 => active
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody'); // 0 => all ; 1 => Process 1 ; 2 => Process 2 ; 3 => ...
var tables_rows = Array.from(tables).map(table => Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName('tr')));
var cells = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('td')).concat(Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('th')));

var employeesCheckboxes = Array.from(filters[0].getElementsByClassName('ckkBox'));
var processCheckboxes = Array.from(filters[1].getElementsByClassName('ckkBox'));
var activeCheckboxes = Array.from(filters[2].getElementsByClassName('ckkBox'));

let employeesStatus = {};
let processStatus = {};
let activeStatus = {};

employeesCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
   if (checkbox.checked && checkbox.value === 'all') {
      employeesStatus['all'] = true;
   } else {
      let noSpacesValue = checkbox.value.split(' ').join('');
      employeesStatus[noSpacesValue] = checkbox.checked;
   }
});

      processCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
   if (checkbox.checked && checkbox.value === 'all') {
      processStatus['all'] = true;
   } else {
      let noSpacesValue = checkbox.value.split(' ').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join('');
      processStatus[noSpacesValue] = checkbox.checked;
   }
});

activeCheckboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
   if (checkbox.checked && checkbox.value === 'all') {
      activeStatus['all'] = true;
   } else {
      let noSpacesValue = checkbox.value.split(' ').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase()).join('');
      activeStatus[noSpacesValue] = checkbox.checked;
   }
});

tables_rows.forEach((table) => {
   table.forEach((row, index) => {
      if (index !== 0 && index !== table.length - 1) {
         let employee = row.childNodes[1].classList[0];
         let val = row.getAttribute('value');
         if (employeesStatus['all']) {
            if ((activeStatus['Active'] && val === 'false') || (activeStatus['Inactive'] && val === 'true') || (activeStatus['all'])) {
               row.style.display = '';
            } else {
               row.style.display = 'none';
            }
        } else {
            if (employeesStatus[employee] && ((activeStatus['Active'] && val === 'false') || (activeStatus['Inactive'] && val === 'true') || (activeStatus['all']))) {
               row.style.display = '';
            } else {
               row.style.display = 'none';
            }
         }
      }
   });
}); // Employee filter & Active filter

Object.keys(processStatus).forEach((process) => {
   cells.forEach((cell) => {
      if (cell.classList.contains(process)) {
         if (processStatus[process] || processStatus['all']) {
            cell.style.display = '';
         } else {
            cell.style.display = 'none';
         }
      }
   });
}); // Process filter
```

Edit n°2 with the HTML of the table / php

````html
<table id="all_process_table" class='table_to_export'>
            <tr>
                <th id="date-th"><?php echo 'Du ' . $start_date . "<br>" . 'au ' . $end_date ?></th>
                <?php
                foreach ($process as $proc) {
                ?>
                    <th scope="col" class="<?php echo removeSpaces($proc) ?>"><?php echo $proc ?></th>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                <th scope="col" class="total-row">Total</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($assigned as $index => $person) {
            ?>
                <tr value="<?php echo $inactive->$person ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>">
                    <th scope="row" class="<?php echo removeSpaces($person) ?>"><?php echo customizeCapitalization($person) . ' [' . ($index + 1) . '] - ' . ($inactive->$person ? 'INACTIF' : 'ACTIF') ?></th>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($process as $proc) {
                    ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo removeSpaces($person) . ' ' . removeSpaces($proc) ?>">
                            <?php
                            $timeValue = $pivotTable[$person][$proc];
                            $formattedTime = $timeValue == 0 ? '' : floatval(number_format($timeValue, 2));
                            echo $formattedTime;
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <td class="<?php echo removeSpaces($person) . ' total-row' ?>"></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="total-col">Total</th>
                <?php
                foreach ($process as $proc) {
                ?>
                    <td class="<?php echo removeSpaces($proc) . ' total-col' ?>"></td>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                <td class="total-col total-row">
                    <b></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    ```

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGJAe.png
````

Comment: hi, can you show us your markup? how do you pass ```display: none``` to your element?

Comment: You will have to keep track if rows are not visible. You shouldn't have to analyze your styling. You could add an attribute (`data-shown`) or similar and simply check for that. FYI: `... .map(th => th.classList[0]).remove(undefined);` seems like an oversight. Does removing `undefined` from a classlist do anything?

Comment: Can you paste the HTML?

Comment: @MahdiarMransouri I updated it with the js you asked

Comment: @PeterKrebs removing the undefined is "needed" because on the row, i can have no class on a th/td so the result of classList will be undefined

Comment: But couldn't you simply not call the remove function then? If the class list has values, removing undefined also doesn't do anything. I was just curious, apparently not the source of your problem.

Comment: You have `const employees = Array.from(trs.map(tr => tr.childNodes[1].classList[0])).remove('total-col');`.  The first part (before remove) returns an array of classlists.  However arrays don’t have a .remove method.  You would need to perform the classList remove on each element instead of the whole array.  Also I’d imagine this does not return `employees` correctly.  I would expect this to throw an error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```js
function countTotal() {
   const tables = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('tbody'));
   tables.forEach(table => {
      const trs = Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName('tr')).slice(1);
      const employees = Array.from(trs.map(tr => tr.childNodes[1].classList[0])).remove('total-col');

      employees.forEach(employee => {
         let colSum = 0;
         const cells = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName(employee)).slice(1, -1);
         cells.forEach(cell => {
            const textContent = parseFloat(cell.innerHTML.trim());
            
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

            if (cell.style.display !== 'none') {
               colSum += !Number.isNaN(textContent) ? textContent : 0;
            }

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

         });
         let cellToFill = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName(employee)).slice(-1)[0];
         cellToFill.textContent = colSum.round(2);
      });

      const processes = Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('th')).map(th => th.classList[0]).remove(undefined);
      processes.forEach(process => {
         let rowSum = 0;
         const cells = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName(process)).slice(1, -1);
         cells.forEach(cell => {
            const textContent = parseFloat(cell.innerHTML.trim());
            
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

            if (cell.parentNode.style.display !== 'none') {
               rowSum += !Number.isNaN(textContent) ? textContent : 0;
            }

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

         });
         let cellToFill = Array.from(table.getElementsByClassName(process)).slice(-1)[0];
         cellToFill.textContent = rowSum.round(2);
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).